# No FREE Tier compute instances available in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

"Get free hands-on experience with popular products, including Compute Engine and Cloud Storage, up to monthly limits. **These free services don't expire**." - Team, first time I'm trying to create a free tier(F1-micro) VM instance and it's not available for selection. The min I can choose in the defined NA locations is e-micro instances. Is there any special buttons I have to use to select free tier instance?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is found. Not really visible, but it's there. This can be completed. Sorry for a noob question.

You have to select Series N1 first and then Machine type f1-micro.